How to write logstash data to cnosdb？
According to the documentation cnosdb supports writing bulk protocol data. Logstash collects log data and writes it to es, which also uses the same protocol. In theory, the same data can also be written to cnosdb. So how can I configure logstash to write logs directly to cnosdb?
